# Trying to keep the burger menu icon fixed to the left side and not move when the burger menu opens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to get the burger icon in my site to not move when the burger menu opens but I'm having issues with keeping it fixed to the left side of the page.

I've tried keeping it fixed by putting in `position: fixed` but that did'nt work. I think the issue might be due to this line:

```
<div id="main">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>  
  
</div>
```

Code for burger menu function-

CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>

  </div>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removenthis line from your script: document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";

You're giving it 250px of left margin which is pushing it out when you click on it.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>

  </div>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch was right. The button moves with the `<div id="main">` container, though `position: fixed;` should prevent that.

Since the button element should not move with the main container, just remove it from that container in the same hierarchy as the sidebar and the main div.

Then add the following rules to the CSS of the button.

```
.openbtn {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

This will make your button fixed to the screen and above the, also fixed, sidebar element.

I hope this is what you meant. Check out the example below.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 9;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 75px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰</button>

  <div id="main">
   
  </div>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This isnt 100% what I what I wanted but all I believe I'd need to do is make the z-index less to hide it behind the burger menu. BUT this adds an interesting visual that I didnt consider (i.e. the burger icon appearing on the far left yet still visible in the burger menu itself), initially I just wanted it to be completely hidden behind the burger menu itself, but this is cool too. Thanks for the help man, I appreciate it!